# Custom GridView Pagination

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, custom-server-controls

I started to work on a custom Gridview extension. I added some basic css stuff, looks ok, now I would like to move on.
I never worked with custom control events.

I currently have an error "event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled."

I have the MyGridview class in a something.aspx.
I'd like to handle pagination in the MyGridview class (not in the something.aspx)

I thought I'd do it like this, because it will pretty much look the same in all the screens.

Can anyone tell me how can I create / override pagination stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than create a derived control, look at skinning it.  Then you can handle the events as necessary from the standard control.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this event:

```
protected void gvName_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gvToPage = (sender as GridView);
    gvToPage.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
}
```

Comment: @Swoosh - sorry type-o; should be PageIndexChanging not PageIndexChanged.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: ok, it kinda works, but this is not what i wanted.
is there a way to move some "similar" code in the MyGridView's class file? so i wouldn't need this code in each list screen i use?
thanks

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you ought to be able to use that directly in MyGridView class to capture the event.